# Handling errors with php on nginx reverse proxy, and mail response to admins

Tags: php, email, nginx, error-handling, reverse-proxy

The question is:
**Is there a way to access the server response from php once Nginx detects an error, and mail the server response to the admins while at the same time show a custom error page to the visitor?**

The best workaround for now is to mail the relevant information directly from the backend servers, but I just can´t thrust them to always send me the email. I want to detect the HTTP error response code in the reverse-proxy and act accordingly regardless of what the backend server is doing.

Currently I am able to delegate error pages to PHP and from there can I send a mail to the admin with the information I get from nginx about the request, but it detects everything as a GET request, looses all POST information, and I have found no way to access the actual response so I can mail that to the admin, so basically I'm sending a very incomplete report about the error.

Is there a way to not loose the POST information, and read the response from the server once the request is delegated to PHP? Is there any other way to mail the error page while at the same time show customized error page?

Please have in mind that the backend servers are remote machines not necessarily under my control. Those servers are sending Nginx all the information it needs to do what I want, it just seems to be a lacking feature on nginx, but I hope someone can think of a workaround or something...

This is my current nginx setup (The GET params attached to the `error_page` clause are the only way I found to pass some information to PHP about the backend server that generated the error):

```
location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_connect_timeout 4s;
        proxy_pass $scheme://hsbservers_$scheme;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_502 http_504;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        server_tokens off;
}

error_page 500 503 502 504 /error.php?err=$status&svr=$upstream_addr&uperr=$upstream_status&sT=$upstream_response_time&pT=$request_time;

location ~ error\.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
}
```

This is an example of the email I'm sending from PHP for a POST request that generated an error:

```
_SERVER
Array
(
    [USER] => www-data
    [HOME] => /var/www
    [FCGI_ROLE] => RESPONDER
    [QUERY_STRING] => err=500&svr=45.79.216.211:443&uperr=500&sT=1.476&pT=1.610
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [CONTENT_TYPE] => multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarydq4hsdTNEzIU6Vve
    [CONTENT_LENGTH] => 9550
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /usr/share/nginx/html/error.php
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /error.php
    [REQUEST_URI] => /node/add/article
    [DOCUMENT_URI] => /error.php
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /usr/share/nginx/html
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => nginx/1.4.6
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 181.49.223.170
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 42033
    [SERVER_ADDR] => 172.31.55.210
    [SERVER_PORT] => 443
    [SERVER_NAME] => _
    [HTTPS] => on
    [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
    [HTTP_HOST] => hsbnoticias.com
    [HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive
    [HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH] => 9550
    [HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL] => max-age=0
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*\/*;q=0.8
    [HTTP_ORIGIN] => https://hsbnoticias.com
    [HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS] => 1
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36
    [HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE] => multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarydq4hsdTNEzIU6Vve
    [HTTP_REFERER] => https://hsbnoticias.com/node/add/article
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => es-ES,es;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
    [HTTP_COOKIE] => /* I removed this for security */
    [PHP_SELF] => /error.php
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1456243321.1031
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1456243321
)


_POST
Array
(
)


_GET
Array
(
    [err] => 500
    [svr] => 45.79.216.211:443
    [uperr] => 500
    [sT] => 1.476
    [pT] => 1.610
)
```

Comment: Obviously the PHP gets everything from a GET request because you send everything as a get request according to line 11 in your nginx config. nginx behaves on O.S. level, if you want more information on your *POST* request you should do that in a global error handling page in PHP. You can use the `header()` function to specifically refer to an error number if so desired.

Comment: Can you think of any way not to send it as a GET request?

Comment: I know I can do this on the backend servers but I want to have an extra layer of error handling in the proxy precisely in case the backend server does not behave as expected which is very common due to the fact that they are under continuous development. 

Please have in mind that the backend servers are remote machines not necessarily under my control. Those servers are sending Nginx all the information it needs to do what I want, it just seems to be a lacking feature on nginx, but I hope someone can think of a workaround or something...

Comment: If I understand correctly what @Xorifelse says, they suggests implementing an error handler in the backend servers and send the email from that point instead of sending it from the proxy. I think that seems to be the only way for now, but it would be far more mantainable and decoupled to mail the actual output from the server directly from the proxy.

Comment: If php crashes you loose all the info anyway. You can try to add a failover.php catch all to `try_files $uri /index.php;`. Nginx will try to post in order to those files.

Comment: All php is doing at this point is to print a static html error file and sending an email which fails silently. I don´t see the point on setting up a fallback functionality for that... What I want is to capture errors from the backend servers and mail those to the admin while presenting a nice static error page to the visitor.

Comment: If you don't need real time reporting, you could modify your access log format to include the post data and then have some script (such as logstash) parse it and send it by email.